# Change the content of PHP classes and methods at runtime, with Reflection?

Tags: php, reflection

**This is for fun only, don't scream please.**

I would like to rewrite the content of a class's methods at runtime (I mean, without modifying the file, only **replacing/editing the code in memory**), is that possible?

Using reflection, or anything else?

Don't close this question please, I'm looking for another answer than runkit.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I think one possible (but wrong way) to go about this would be to call a `file_get_contents` on the file, make the changes needed, then calling an `eval`.  The downside is that you'll have to essentially create a loader because it would be a massive pain (or infinite loop if not careful) to have a file load itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP runtime class modification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593497/php-runtime-class-modification)

Comment: I don't think it should be closed because the only solution proposed in the old duplicate was "runkit", and runkit is very very old... I'm looking for ideas !

Comment: If you don't want to use runkit, the the only other option is [classkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.classkit-method-redefine.php). Likewise old and am not sure if it works on current PHP setups.

Comment: @Matthieu, runkit/classkit (should) still work, and is the only effective way to get this done if the class has already been loaded.

Comment: @Charles "the class has already been loaded" : Well it doesn't have to. What about reading the PHP file in memory (php://memory), modifying it in memory, and then include "php://memory" ?

Comment: @Matthieu, it happens that [`php://memory` is a filehandle](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#example-284), so you wouldn't be able to hand it to `include`.  You'd may as well use `eval` here to get the same effect.  (Okay, you could use [`data:`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php) here, but that's restricted when `allow_url_include` is disabled, which it'd better be.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply create a new class that inherits from the one you want to modify and overwrite it's methods?

```
<?php
class MySimpleXML extends SimpleXMLElement {
    public function themethodiwanttooverwrite() {
        //...
    }
}
?>
```

As long as the method isn't marked as final...

Comment: Yes but I'd have to change the code that is using the class too (to make it use my class), which I don't want to do :(