# Dynamic php method

Tags: php, dynamic, methods, dynamic-method

Is it possible to create a method dynamically? For example: I have a method called "createMethod()". I would like to pass variables to this method describing how the dynamic method would look like (function description, params as an array or object). I have been trying to make something like that, bet I've got stuck at describing params and got mixed up with eval() function, that I used to form some variables.

Could someone give me a simple example how this dynamic method would look like? Maby there are something helpful already created in Zend or CodeIgniter frameworks?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, look at [`__call`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call), which catches any calls to methods that do not exist. You can make a dynamic call using `$method = 'callme'; $this->$method($params)`.

Comment: Can you concretise the use case / context?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good solution at:
[php create class method at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985926/php-create-class-method-at-runtime)

Is a mix of the magic method __call and closures.

And this a post about how [extending objects with new methods at runtime](http://www.stubbles.org/archives/65-Extending-objects-with-new-methods-at-runtime.html)

Answer (score 0):

php magic method __call][1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) could be what youre looking for