# How can I change existing function in a class

Tags: php, class

I have a form class and I want define different functions when form be submitted.

```
<?php

class Forms {

    function __construct() {
        if (!empty($_POST['exampleInput'])) {
            $this->PostedForms();
        }
    }

    function __call($func, $param) {

    }

    function PostedForms() {
        if (!empty($_POST['exampleInput'])) {
            if (function_exists($this->userDefined)) {
                $this->userDefined();
            }
        }
    }

}

$form = new Forms();
$form->userDefined = function ($param) {
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

I want define userDefined function outside of class. How can I do this? Can I change any function of class after class was called? Can I change ***userDefined = function ($param) {print_r($_GET);}*** for example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php create class method at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985926/php-create-class-method-at-runtime)

Comment: @Whirlwind, that's the same one.

Comment: check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938004/how-to-add-a-new-method-to-a-php-object-on-the-fly