# Eval Interface with const attributes

Tags: php, eval

This's my code:

```
$array = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Paul',
    'current_job' => 'coder'
);
$interface = 'interface PropertyInterface {';

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $interface .= 'const '.strtoupper($key).' = '.$value.';';
}

$interface .= '}';
eval($interface);

class Foo implements PropertyInterface
{

}
```

when running:

```
var_dump(Foo::ID);
```

it working, return 1, but when running:

```
var_dump(Foo::NAME);
```

or:

```
var_dump(Foo::CURRENT_JOB);
```

it not working, this is error:

Use of undefined constant toan - assumed...

what's wrong? somebody can help me?

Comment: *what's wrong?* You're abusing the language.  Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish and maybe we can help you find a better solution to your problem.

Comment: i want create dynamic const property for class Foo :D

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203625/dynamically-generate-classes-at-runtime-in-php

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are concatenating `$value` as constant.

```
$interface .= 'const '.strtoupper($key).' = '.$value.';';
```

Above translates to:

```
const NAME = Paul;
```

You need to wrap in double quotes `"'.$value.'"`

```
$interface .= 'const '.strtoupper($key).' = "'.$value.'";';
```

Which translates to:

```
const NAME = "Paul";
```

Comment: `$value` is probably user input, so using `eval()` to create a dynamic class in this way is likely a very bad idea, especially since the OP seems to lack a basic understanding of things like knowing the difference between a constant and a string.